# Need help translating function from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need some help translating this code from c# to vb.net:

```
    private static Action<int, int> TranslateOrigin(Action<int, int> f, int x, int y)
    {
        return (a, b) => f(a + x, b + y);
    }
```

The automatic translators I've found on the internet make a mess of it, producing:

```
Private Shared Function TranslateOrigin(f As Action(Of Integer, Integer), x As Integer, y As Integer) As Action(Of Integer, Integer)
    Return Function(a, b) f(a + x, b + y)
End Function
```

Which won't compile, complaining that "Expression doe not produce a value."
I've been poking at it for a while now and haven't had any luck translating it, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 the automatic translators are rubbish at lambdas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a bit closer since it doesn't return a value, but rather an action. using a single line.

```
Public Shared Function TranslateOrigin(f As Action(Of Integer, Integer), x As Integer, y As Integer) As Action(Of Integer, Integer)
    Return Sub(a, b) f(a + x, b + y)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Private Shared Function TranslateOrigin(ByVal f As Action(Of Integer, Integer), ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Action(Of Integer, Integer)
     Return Function (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) 
               f.Invoke((a + x), (b + y))
            End Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that an [`Action(Of T1, T2)` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549311.aspx) does not return a value? If it is anyway what you want (though I don't see much of a point in it, with value types), you can use a Sub.

> Encapsulates a method that has two parameters and does not return a value.

With a sub, that will give this code:

```
Private Shared Function TranslateOrigin(f As Action(Of Integer, Integer), x As Integer, y As Integer) As Action(Of Integer, Integer)
    Return Sub(a, b) f(a + x, b + y)
End Function
```

You probably want to return a value, therefor you'll need a [`Func(Of T1, T2, TResult)` delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx). In your case, that would make:

```
Private Shared Function TranslateOrigin(f As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Integer), x As Integer, y As Integer) As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)
    Return Function(a, b) f(a + x, b + y)
End Function
```

Calling it as below, will return the value `6` (as I guess is expected):

```
TranslateOrigin(Function(x, y) x + y, 1, 2)(1, 2)
```